# NodeJs parent function variable appears to be out of scope in async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this code:

```
function mainProcess(res) {  
async.waterfall([

        function(callback) {
            postExportDefinition(requestParams, callback);
        },

        function(requestParams, callback) {
            postSync(requestParams, callback);
        },

        function(requestParams, callback) {
            checkSync(requestParams, callback);
        },
        function(body, callback) {
            postUpdatedData(body, callback);
        },
        function(syncUri, callback) {
            getSyncResponseInIntervals(syncUri, callback);
        }
    ],

    // the bonus final callback function
    function(err, status) {

        if (err) {
            res.status(500)
                .send({
                    error: "Error (best handling ever)"
                });
            return;
        }
        if (ageOffset < 100){
            mainProcess();
        }else{
            res.send("Success: " + status);
            console.log(status);
            return;
        }
    });
 }
```

The `res` is `undefined` and I kind of understand why, but what is the right approach to be able to use `res` within the `waterfall`?

One solution would be to pass the variable along in all the functions and all the callbacks, but that is not scalable at all and I hate such solution. Is it the only one?

Another solution would be to make res global for entire script, again, doesn't feel right.

**EDIT:**
`res` is undefined only in the last recursion call, which I don't understand can it be something that `res` object has expired? I am using `express` framework and the last call has happened after 60s.

**EDIT2:**

It's all my fault, I was calling `mainProcess` also from one of the functions when age range wasn't suitable. That broke it. That was some legacy code that was left over.

Comment: Where exactly is `res` `undefined`? In `res.send("Success: " + status);`?

Comment: Here: `res.send("Success: " + status);`

Comment: Then something passed `undefined` to `mainProcess`. If `res` was not accessible at all (which is not the case), then you would get a reference error.

Comment: Not really, it works just fine if I make `res` variable global.

Comment: unless there is an argument name res in the last function that is not shown or a new `var res = ` delaration in the same function, res is visible via closure

Comment: Well, the problem is certainly not scope (JavaScript has lexical scope, every function is a closure). The code you posted should work just fine. So either it's a problem with how the function is called or you have removed the parts that are problematic.

Answer (score 1):

unless there is an argument name res in the last function that is not shown or a new `var res =` delaration in the same function, res is visible via closure

The only way i see res being undefined is the code on

```
if (ageOffset < 100){
   mainProcess();
}
```

executing which calls the mainProcess function recursively without passing the `res` variable, which on that call will be undefined

if you need the recursive call and the logic behind the code stands change it as follows

```
if (ageOffset < 100){
   mainProcess(res); // pass res again to mainProcess
}
```

Comment: I've tried to pass `res` variable as a parameter as exactly that were my thoughts, but it didn't help.

Comment: @OndrejTokar then on the initial call of mainProcess res is undefined. have a console.log statement test that

Comment: It's strange, when I log the res object inside the callback function, it says it's undefined. But when I log it before waterfall is called, it shows the object... so where is it getting lost.

Comment: But you should know that the final callback function that handles errors and successes is called from inside the last waterfall function. But that is the standard async.waterfall pattern so  I assume you know it.

Comment: No the entire code is too big. But if you assume my code is good, then I need to find the bug, it might be outside of the code I posted. I will keep you updated. Thank you.

Comment: I have renamed the variable to response to make sure I am not changing res anywhere. Didn't help.

Comment: have you changed `if (ageOffset < 100){ mainProcess();}` to include res?

Comment: Yes I have and it works up until last recursion, then it becomes undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks absolutely fine. If you are getting res printed before waterfall & in waterfall's final callback its undefined means its getting changed in mid.

Ensure no where you are altering the **res** within any of the waterfall blocks or redeclaring as **var res**.

If you are still getting the issue, then debug it by each waterfall block level(Check for res in each block). So that which place its getting replaced you can get.

Update:

In the final callback atleast one time it should print res properly.

```
 function(err, status) {
   //Here it should print once at least
    console.log(res);
    if (err) {
    ...
    }
    if (ageOffset < 100){
        //here u r making res undefined for the next call. Since its not passed. If u pass it will still work
        mainProcess();
    }else{
        res.send("Success: " + status);
        console.log(status);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I have renamed the variable to response to make sure I am not changing res anywhere. Didn't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you check is it going within if block  if (ageOffset < 100{mainProcess();}

Comment: IGNORE THIS ONE: A note to your latest update, even the first time where I do the console.log my res variable is undefined. Even before I am recursively calling mainProcess.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, I was wrong. Only the last res is undefined, every other res is fine object.

Comment: Did You check within each block of waterfall. Like after which its become undefined?

Comment: @OndrejTokar I couldnt get u clearly.. So one time it prints and on another recurssion it failed is it?

Comment: For some reason it becomes undefined in the last recursive call.

Comment: Your final callback takes only parameter as (err, status) right. Not as (err, res)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117696/discussion-between-jerry-and-ondrej-tokar).